# Listing of United States Police Departments?

Tags: usa, police

Is there a list of the US Police Departments maintained at a federal level? I know the DOJ is supposed to be over them all? Does it maintain any such list, or any other federal agency?

Answer (score 1):

Here's two you can piece together:

- [Agency Participation Data in FBI NIBRS](http://s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/cg-d3f0433b-a53e-4934-8b94-c678aa2cbaf3/agencies.csv) from [FBI Crime Data Explorer](https://crime-data-explorer.fr.cloud.gov/)
- (not open) [Directory of Law Enforcement Agencies, 1996: [United States] (ICPSR 2260)](https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/NACJD/studies/2260/version/1)

Comment: Were did you source the FBI NIBRS data?

Comment: edited answer with it

Comment: its the caption citation underneath the map image